# Python Server Client Connection

Tags: python, sockets, server, clients

I would like to know how to make it possible for a python server to wait for messages from 2 clients without any pre-assumption as to who would be messaging first. Can I do something like--
message=client.recv(BUFSIZ) or targetsoc.recv(BUFSIZ)
Can I try something like this where both targetsoc and client are client sockets connected to each other and I donno who would be messaging first?

I basically want to be able to listen for data from both the clients simultaneously without any order or priority...

Comment: Use [select](http://pymotw.com/2/select/).

Comment: I mean I need to let both the clients in a connection send messages and the order of communication need not be fixed or pre-empted....Is the above method valid? like can I keep both the sockets alive simultaneously and see which one sends a message first?